# Android News Feed Application

Tags: android

This is more of a theoretical question.
I have developed a newsfeed android app. I want the users to comment on the post(just like facebook). How to procedd with this. What actually happens in the background. For instance:
User A posts something and its shown on User B mobile. Now User B comments on that. This comment should reflect in User A mobile ( ofcourse, it has to be real time with notification shown on User A mobile) How should I proceed

Answer (score -1):

- you need a database, which receives and stores the posts users make, can be a simple MySQL database.
- and you need a backend, which handles the communication between the users device and your database, doing tasks like inserting posts into the database, notificating users (though push), when something interesting happens. Backend can be made for example with PHP or Ruby.

Comment: That's right. You can also use a mutli platform push notification service (e.g. https://onesignal.com/ or zer0Push). It makes it easier to implenent push both, for android and iOS.